# How to pull out a specific value from a python pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a newbie of pandas, and have a quick and stupid question about Python Panda package: How to pull out a specific value from a data frame?

The structure of data frame likes:

```
           id           ba_ntr
0           1            PRF
1           2            PUF
.....
3898     3444       PRF
```

I then use the code likes the following to pull out a specific value:

```
list(df[df['id'] == 25]['ba_ntr']) == ['PUF']
```

In the code above, I am trying to:

1. Find the line in which the value of column `id` is 25. All the
   values in `id` are unique but not continuous - one of the reason
   that I did not use index.
2. Because all the values in `id` are unique, `df[df['id'] == 25]` should
   return one row, and I then need to know the value of column `ba_ntr`
   in that line.
3. Because `df[df['id'] == 25]['ba_ntr']` will return a pandas Series, I
   use `list()` to convert the Series to list, and compare with another
   list `['PUF']`.
4. I believe converting series to list is unnecessary and
   time-consuming - I have 5 million lines of records to iterate...

**So thank you for saving my time and life!**

Comment: if you want just the scalar value then `df.loc[df['id'] == 25,'ba_ntr'].values[0]` will return the scalar value

Comment: will this faster than I use list()?

Comment: probably but not by much as the main thing is the indexing part, converting the series to a list will add some minor overhead but I expect just accessing the np array will be faster

Comment: Also what are you trying to do here? It looks like you're trying to match your id values against a list? are you just wanting to test for membership of a list of values?

Comment: I want to compare the value of ba_ntr in a specific row, whether it is PUF or PRF. Any better strategy?

Comment: You mean compare against a string? Are these matches pre-defined? you'd better first to filter the df `matches = df[df['id'].isin(my_list_of_ids)]` then you can match the str values. The PUF/PRF are these values matched already against a list of ids or are you just wanting to count the different values?

Answer (score 0):

If your `id` column is indeed unique, why not just use it as the index? (there is no requirement that the index be continuous)

```
df.set_index('id', drop=True, inplace=True)
# or, if you don't want to mangle the existing data frame
# df_reindexed = df.set_index('id', drop=True)
is_puf = df.loc[25, 'ba_ntr'] == 'PUF'
```

Comment: This being said, I hope you have a good reason for element-wise iteration! What is your end goal?